# Websockets send message in sync function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm using websockets and asyncio to manage connections in my app.

The send method is async

```
async def send(self, message):
        logging.debug('send {}'.format(message))
        await self.websocket.send(message)
```

and i usually use it in async threads and everything is ok.
There is only one situation where i need to call it from a sync method.

I have tried to call it in this way

```
asyncio.run(ws.send(json.dumps(payload)))
```

but i get this exception

```
Task <Task pending name='Task-134' coro=<WebSocketCommonProtocol.send() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py:631> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py:184]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

So I tried to use the current loop

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.run(ws.send(json.dumps(payload)), loop=loop)
```

but

```
There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-37'.
```

What can be done?

Comment: Is your script mixing `asyncio` and `threading`? Might be better to put threads on `asyncio` side using [`asyncio.to_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread)

Comment: the major problem is that `self.websocket...`  will be tied to a different loop than the one in the separate thread from which you are trying the sync call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one thread which is running the async code you should launch a task that goes listening to a queue - and whenever it gets something, it processes the request and post the result back.

That way on the sync thread you just have to post to that queue and wait for the result. The Queue iteself is for inter-thread communication and does not need to be async itself - so queue.Queue is a class you can use, and then use asyncio.sleep to just pool the queue at regular intervals.

So, more or less along this:

```
from queue import Queue, Empty
import threading

class YouDidNotPostTheClass:

   def __init__(self, ...):
       ...
       self.queue = Queue()
   
   async def _async_init(self):
       # this method is boilerplate - you could
       # just issue the call bellow wherever you start your async code
       self._tasks = [asyncio.create_task(self.sync_send_server()), ]

   async def _async_end(self):
       for task in self._tasks:
           task.cancel()
   
   async def sync_send_server(self):
        while True:
            try:
                message = self.queue.get_nowait()
            except Empty:
                pass
            else:
                await self.send(message)
            await asyncio.sleep(0.05) # Tune at will
            self.queue.task_done()  # <- optional, but ensure you can use all of Queue's functionality on your code.

    def sync_send(self, message):
         # call _this_ method from the thread running sync code
         self.queue.put(message)
    
    async def send(self, message):
        ...


...
async def main():
     client = YouDidNotPostTheClass()
     await client._async_init()
     # your main async code goes here
     ...
     # avoid warnings about running tasks at program end:
     await client._async_end()

def sync_main():
    # code to drive the synchronous thread in your program
    ...

syncthread = threading.Thread(target=sync_main)
syncthread.start()
asyncio.run(main()
```